How to maintain distance in objects, inside particle system (the object here is joined and is not one simple sphere/cube)
I want to fill my icosphere with particles. However, my particles are basically three parallel sheets that I joined together. No problem, I joined them and made them an object, putting them into the 'Render as' object inside the particle system for my ico-sphere. Here's my problem: I don't want my object(s) to touch each other. (I have selected the source as volume). I understood that to avoid objects touching; we can use nodes, which distribute points on faces/volumes. My question is how to select that particular object I created by joining three sheets and using it in the geometry node. In simple terms, how do I add a grouped object into the geometry node so that I can use the distance function and they don't make contact? I'm fine with reducing the no. of particles as long as they don't touch. Thank you so much for your help.

I would say: Geometry nodes are not the right choice here, as you cannot reliably detect collisions in the case of complex meshes and react accordingly.
